# Copy, verify, and then delete files/children from network location

Tags: networking, powershell, xcopy, robocopy

I want to develop a script that copies,verifies, and then deletes from one network location to another (files over x days old).

Here is my algorithm:

```
Recursively traverse a network location ($movePath)
for all files $_.LastWriteTime >= x days | forEach {
   xcopy or robocopy $FileName = $_.FullName.Replace($movePath, $newPath)
   if (the files where written correctly) {
     (delete) Remove-Item $Filename from $movePath
   }
```

Can I combine the `xcopy /v` (verify) with robocopy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to maintain the subfolder structure (i.e. files from a subfolder in the source go into the same subfolder in the destination)? If so, this should suffice:

```
$src = 'D:\source\folder'
$dst = '\\server\share'
$age = 10  # days

robocopy $src $dst /e /move /minage:$age
```

`robocopy` can handle verification (done automatically) and deletion by itself.

Comment: and how about if I want a log of the move? Does robocopy generate one?

Comment: Will this work? robocopy $src $dst /e /move /minage:$age /LOG+:$logFile

Comment: It should, yes. `/log+:` will append to the log if it already exists, or create a new log if the file doesn't exist. If you want to overwrite an existing log use `/log:` instead.